# How to use git reset in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, git-reset

I want to undo my last commit in NetBeans.

As I found the command is '$ git reset --soft HEAD~ ' but how can I do it in NetBeans7 IDE?

Comment: I use Team -> Revert -> Revert Commit

Comment: But it seems it does a --hard reset not --soft.

Comment: and also the commit is still in the history

Answer (score 2):

- Use Main menu: Team -> Git -> Reset... (NB 7.3.x) OR
- Use Main menu: Team -> Git-> Revert/Recover-> Reset... (or use the context menu) (NB 7.4)